# Tomcat6, SSL, Windows - connector issues

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I've been asked to move an http tomcat install to https.

We've ordered and installed the cert and have followed the directions given by the application developer that are not working - so went and found other directions, ending up with the following for our connector port configuration:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="KeyStoreFileThatIsInSameDirectoryAsServer.xml" 
           keystorePass="*********"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Now, http and https just spin on us.

I am not familiar with Tomcat, but the logs I am finding are not showing connections or issues when I am testing.

We don't want to disable http until we get https working for the application.

When I used the following I could use http, but https was just ignored completly.

```
           keystoreFile="%SINGULARITY_HOME%\lib\tomcat\conf\Keystore"
```

Any pointers on where to look for the proper logs or glaring misteps in my connector port info?

Comment: When you say https was ignored, you mean that you can access Tomcat on port 8443 over HTTP? eg. http://localhost:8443?

Comment: Sorry no. I can not access with https://url  or with localhost:8443  or with http://localhost  - browser displays IE cannot display the webpage

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question: firewall? :)

Comment: Perfectly fair question. Ports are open on the firewall and testing within the firewall so it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to use the full path instead of relative.  Thanks to the app developer for their eyes on this one.

```
       keystoreFile="FullPathtoKeystore-notRelative"
```